# SCCM deadlined deployment stuck at "In Progress" and "Content Downloaded"

Tags: sccm

We're using SCCM current branch to deploy updates to a line of business app fairly regularly. For a long while, we had it down to a pretty predictable rhythm with a success rate above 95%.  And new update deployments are created by copying the existing one and modifying it with the new version details, so as to keep as much the same as possible.

Somewhat recently, it has stopped working quite so well. In each deployment, we get about 80 systems that are stuck on "In Progress" and "Content Downloaded".

Using [this guide](https://deploymentparts.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/how-to-track-an-installation-through-client-log-files) (which I've used for years), I can follow the deployment down through to file download in ContentTransferManager and CAS, which report that the download is complete.  However, it doesn't then move on to AppEnforce to log that it's starting the install. And I haven't been able to find anything in AppDiscovery or AppIntentEval that says it's delaying the install for any reason.

If I wait, they appear to eventually install sometime over the next week, I'm presuming when the next automatic app eval cycle completes on each system.  If I right-click the collection and force an app eval cycle, they report back rather quickly (usually within 5 or 10 minutes) that they've completed successfully.

I'm struggling to find any info about what's supposed to trigger the next step, or any other troubleshooting where it seems it just fails to continue.  I'm hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been something wrong with the application definition itself within SCCM.  If I recreate the package from scratch, the deployment works without issue.  I had forgotten I had come across this situation before a long while back, and this solution fixed it.  I had hoped at the time the newly created package would be free of this issue, but unfortunately not.